# Display splashview on start and hide it after 2 seconds with curl animation

Tags: ios

I'm displaying a splashview on start of my application and after 2 seconds i move it out to the right. This works fine :)

But now I(or better somebody else) want a curlup animation to hide the splashview. And I don't get it to work :(

I added a containerView with two imageViews. One with the splashImage and one with an transparent image. And now I want to switch them...

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.containerView cache:YES];

[self.splashView removeFromSuperview];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.splashViewTrans];    

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

With this code it shows nothing. No transition and no splashImage...

Does anyone solve this and can give me a tip?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `commitAnimations` before removing the `splashView`—the `splashView` is disappearing before the animation occurs. `setAnimationTransition:forView:cache:` only creates an animation; to display it you have to `commit` it.

Comment: Hello Inspire48,
thanks for this :)

This was one point to solve the problem :)